# Does System.Windows.Forms.Timer send WM_TIMER message?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

Does System.Windows.Forms.Timer send WM_TIMER message ?

Basically I want to set a timer that should generate

```
WM_TIMER
```

message for every 5 seconds. I am using

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer
```

and the

```
Tick
```

event is handled. But I am not getting WM_TIMER message in my WndProc().

Comment: Yes, it does use `WM_TIMER`. It uses a separate hidden window for that, that's why you don't see it in your `WndProc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, WM_TIMER is what makes a Winforms Timer tick.  Unobserved in your code however, it creates its *own* window, it doesn't use yours.  It is an invisible one, the underlying .NET class is TimerNativeWindow, a *private* class of the Timer class.  You can't ever override its WndProc().  Technically you could subclass it with NativeWindow after digging out the handle with Reflection, but that way lies dragons and should never be necessary.