# Asynchronous Displaying in Windows Form Application c#

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, count

I don't think the following question is rarely seen. But since I don't know how to search for the right answer, so I'm still stuck on it.

I have a label in the form and I want to show some words simultaneously

```
    public string[] words = new string[]{"add", "ado", "age", "ago", "aid", "ail", "aim", "air", "and", "any", "ape", "apt", "arc", "are", "ark", "arm",
        "art", "ash", "ask", "auk", "awe", "awl", "aye", "bad", "bag", "ban", "bat", "bee", "boa", "ear", "eel", "eft",
        "far", "fat", "fit", "lee", "oaf", "rat", "tar", "tie"};

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 39; i++)
        {
            label1.Text = words[i];
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
```

The label just show "eft" and won't show anything before "for" is complete.

Comment: Why don't you try a Timer control in Windows Application? set proper interval and disable timer once when its done

Comment: @MuhammedShevilKP  My question is just one example

Comment: `I want to show some words simultaneously` It doesn't look like that's what you are trying to do. *Simultaneously* would mean they are all visible at the same time --> `label1.Text = String.Join(" ", words);`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should be using a System.Windows.Forms.Timer to update - otherwise you are blocking the main thread.  However, you can call Form.Refresh to force an update in your loop.

Comment: The usage of Timer means that the task will be executed in on ThreadPool Thread. Wouldn't that create issues with accessing UI controls? Wouldn't it require a context switching, resulting in performance impact? Not sure, why you consider this solution ideal.

Comment: @3615 That's incorrect.  WinForms timer event handlers happens in the UI thread.  No marshalling required.  [WM_TIMER is sent under the hood](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21722684/585968) which is a very WIN32 thing

Comment: @MickyD Ok, thank you for correcting me. But is this also true relateve to System.Threading.Timer? Probably it's obvious that in Windows Forms application is the one to use, but I've based my comment on other Timer class, since it wasn't specified explicitly.

Comment: @3615 No worries. No because System.Threading.Timer uses a different thread. For WinForms apps (OP's question) it is recommended to use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` if you intend to interact with a GUI.  See **Remarks** [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `Task.Delay` that would not block the UI thread:

```
 private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                ((Button) sender).Content = i.ToString();
                await Task.Delay(100);
            }
        }
```

Using this solution would not require any extra threads to be created, so it should be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        label1.Text = i.ToString();
        await Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(100); });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            label1.Text = i.ToString();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
```

call **Application.DoEvents()** in your code, so your app can handle the other events

Comment: `Application.DoEvents()` can lead to _re-entrancy_ of application command handlers; is generally evil; and not kind to puppies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Threading.Timer`:

```
 System.Threading.Timer timer;
 int i=-1;

public string[] words = new string[]{"add", "ado", "age", "ago", "aid", "ail", "aim", "air", "and", "any", "ape", "apt", "arc", "are", "ark", "arm",
        "art", "ash", "ask", "auk", "awe", "awl", "aye", "bad", "bag", "ban", "bat", "bee", "boa", "ear", "eel", "eft",
        "far", "fat", "fit", "lee", "oaf", "rat", "tar", "tie"};
  private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 timer = new System.Threading.Timer(timer_Tick, null, 0, 100); //Time delay 100
 }
 private void timer_Tick(Object state)
        {                
                try
                {

                    i++;


                    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                         label1.Text = words[i];
                         if (i==words.Length )
                          timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
                    });  

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {                      
                }
                finally
                {                      
                }

        }
```

Comment: System.Threading.Timer should not be used in WinForms if the intent is to update the UI. _"[System.Threading.Timer, which executes a single callback method on a thread pool thread at regular intervals.  this class is intended for use as a server-based or service component in a multithreaded environment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)"_. Besides if you use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`  there is no need for Invoke()

Answer (score 0):

```
ThreadStart safir ;
Thread Nakh;
delegate void kar(string p);
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    safir = new ThreadStart(NeveshtanDarBarchasb);
    Nakh =  Thread(safir); 
   Nakh.Start();
}

public void NeveshtanDarBarchasb()
{
  for (int i = 0; i <= 39; i++)
    {
         Benevis(I.ToString());
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
public void Benevis(string p)
{
     if( lbl.InvokeRequired)
     {
          kar k= new kar(Benevis);
          Invoke(k,new object[]{p};
      }
      else
      {
           label1.Text = p;
       }
}
```